# Why does the "choose files" button not work in Wordpress 2.5 when trying to upload photos?

Tags: flash, wordpress, modal-dialog, photos

I've got Wordpress 2.5 installed on my website. It works well, but I can't get the photo uploader to work. When I'm writing a post, I click on the "Add media" button. In the "Choose File" tab, I see the "Choose files to upload" button. When I click on it, nothing happens. I searched the net and found nothing helpful. One page vaguely mentioned having the latest Flash player. I verified and confirmed that I have the latest player. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you are having trouble with the Flash uploader, which was introduced in Wordpress 2.5. You should upgrade Wordpress, which will likely fix the problem. Newer versions of Wordpress also allow you to switch to the "Browser" version of the uploader, which doesn't use Flash.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.9 and both the flash and browser uploaders work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

What happens after you made the upgrade to the latest WordPress (currently 2.9.2)? There are many bugs fixed. 2.5 is old and not secure.

Comment: Thanks. I took the plunge and upgraded to 2.9.2. It worked well.